# Как вернуть кастомный тип из sql функции?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
create type site_common_info as (
  engine    text,
  version   text,
  installed boolean
);


create function get_site_common_info()
  returns site_common_info
AS
$$
  SELECT ROW('MegaEngine', '1.0.2', false);
$$ language sql stable;
```

Error: return type mismatch in function declared to return site_common_info Подробности: Final statement returns record instead of text at column 1. Where: SQL function "get_site_common_info"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ROW` в данном случае не нужно:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION get_site_common_info()
RETURNS site_common_info
AS
$$
  SELECT 'MegaEngine', '1.0.2', FALSE;
$$
LANGUAGE SQL STABLE
;
```

Comment: А, то есть моя ошибка была в том что я возвращал как бы одну ячейку, а должен был вернуть три ячейки, которые бы postgresql конвертнул бы в нужный site_common_info тип)?

Comment: Да.  Ваш ответ, в общем-то, тоже был вполне корректен.  Я даже наооброт, обычно предпочитаю явное приведение типов.

Answer (score 0):

Мы должны добавить явное приведение типа
`::site_common_info`

```
create type site_common_info as (
  engine    text,
  version   text,
  installed boolean
);


create function get_site_common_info()
  returns site_common_info
AS
$$
SELECT ('Mega', '1.0.2', false)::site_common_info;
$$ language sql stable;
```